# Strange hex formatting in NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, hex

Try this:

```
unsigned long long int N; = 23229877463LL;
NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dec:%qi, hex:%qX",N,N];

NSLog(@"output: %@",s);

output: dec:23229877460, hex:689BCCD400000005
```

What's up with the 00000005??? In mySQL, hex(23229877460) = 5689BCCD4. Also, every other language seems to do this correctly. A 16 digit long hex is like 4 gazillion (16^16), right?

How can I get objective-c to format hex numbers that other languages can understand?

Comment: Have you tried without the semicolon after N?

Comment: I haven’t been able to reproduce this on both 32- and 64-bit binaries on Intel Mac OS X 10.6, as well as iOS 4.1 (simulator), using GCC and Clang. By the way, `ULL` and `%qu` should be used for _unsigned_ integers.

Comment: @Bavarious %qX is also for unsigned integers but formatted as hex, which is obviously what's wanted. %q- is deprecated and %ll- is preferred, but I'm sure that's not the problem.

Comment: @pseudopeach: Can you please include more code, and also cut and paste the code. Whatever is causing your problem isn't actually presented here, and since the code is re-typed (obvious because the above code won't even compile plus the assigned number and your output are different even as regular base-10), we can't even point out any typo that might be causing your issue.

Comment: Besides the extra `;`, I've never heard of an `unsigned long long int` before.

Comment: @Jason: I was referring to `%qu` as opposed to `%qi`. It wasn’t clear, I guess. =)

Comment: @Bavarious: Oh, good point, I should have realized that myself!

Comment: @Dave `int` is optional when referring to `short`, `long` or `long long` integers regardless of them being `signed` or `unsigned`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fixing the spurious `;` to yield:

```
unsigned long long int N = 23229877463LL;
NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dec:%qi, hex:%qX",N,N];

NSLog(@"output: %@",s);
```

The code works exactly as expected:

```
2011-01-09 10:46:16.236 dfjkdfkjfdjkfd[25716:a0f] output: dec:23229877463, hex:5689BCCD7
```

There is something else wrong.  You'll need to post more code.   The line used to compile the file would probably be helpful, too.

---

And for giggles:

```
unsigned long long int N = 23229877460LL;
NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dec:%qi, hex:%qX",N,N];
2011-01-09 10:49:10.425 dfjkdfkjfdjkfd[25755:a0f] output: dec:23229877460, hex:5689BCCD4
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what was going wrong with it. I think it was carefully casting everything to a long long. I always see those literal formatting indicators like ,44.5f, 32985209543985LL, and so on, but I've never read about them formally anywhere.